# Does the kernel call try_module_get/module_get when calling a function registered by ko to the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

Current scenario: ko registers a callback function to the kernel(not a ko) in the ko's init function. Will the kernel call try_module_get/module_get before calling back the function?  If it is called, please give a example in kernel. If it is not called, what mechanism is used to ensure that when uninstalling, the kernel does not use ko.Thanks.

Comment: "Will the kernel call try_module_get/module_get before calling back the function?" - Dependent on what **actually** is being registered (a character device, a filesystem, etc.) the kernel could actually call `try_module_get` *some time before* the callback function is called. This is a proper way for ensure that kernel module won't be unloaded while the registered object is in use.

Comment: "**ko registers a callback function to the kernel**". Well, what part of the kernel is it being registered with? Be more specific.

Comment: One example of calling `try_module_get` is in "fs/char_dev.c" when a character-special device is being opened. `chrdev_open` calls `fops_get` which calls `try_module_get` on the module that owns the `struct file_operations` (as set in the `.owner` member). That ensures that the module remains loaded while the device file is open.

Comment: When it comes down to it, it is your responsibility as a programmer to ensure that the callback function cannot be called after the module is unloaded.